# Delphi; Add PopupMenu support to a control without source

Tags: delphi, menu, contextmenu, subclassing

I have a VCL control for which I do not have the source that does not have a PopupMenu property and associated event(s). How can I add this?

The control (per the documentation) inherits from TCustomControl, which inherits from TWinControl.

Looking through the Delphi VCL source it seems to involve handling the WM_CONTEXTMENU message.

I can create the control at runtime, so it doesn't have to support design-time functionality if that makes it simpler.

Delphi 10.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-contextmenu) for `WM_CONTEXTMENU` states, when a child window does not process the message, the default window procedure sends the message to the parent window.

So you can display the popup menu by handling the message on the parent of the control. Below example displays a "PopupMenu1" for a "Panel1" placed on a form, you may need to adjust if your control is not directly placed on the form.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ..
  protected
    procedure WMContextMenu(var Message: TWMContextMenu);
      message WM_CONTEXTMENU;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.WMContextMenu(var Message: TWMContextMenu);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Pt := SmallPointToPoint(Message.Pos);
  Control := ControlAtPos(ScreenToClient(Pt), False, True, True);
  if Control = Panel1 then begin
    PopupMenu1.PopupComponent := Panel1;
    PopupMenu1.Popup(Pt.X, Pt.Y);
    Message.Result := 1;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: For others: My control isn't on the form, so I needed to change the assignement of Control to ""Control := ToolBar1.ControlAtPos(ToolBar1.ScreenToClient(pt), false, true, true)".  Works great.

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- assign a handler to the control's public `WindowProc` property to handle messages directly, like `WM_CONTEXTPOPUP`.

  ```
  var
    OldWndProc: TWndMethod;

  ...

  procedure TMyForm.CreateControl;
  var
    Ctrl: TTheControl;
  begin
    Ctrl := TTheControl.Create(Self);
    OldWndProc := Ctrl.WindowProc;
    Ctrl.WindowProc := MyCtrlWndProc;
    ...
  end;

  procedure TMyForm.MyCtrlWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
    if Message.Msg = WM_CONTEXTMENU then
    begin
      ...
    end;
    OldWndProc(Message);
  end;
  ```
- derive from the control and override its virtual `WndProc()` method.

  ```
  type
    TMyControl = class(TTheControl)
    protected
      procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    end;

  procedure TMyControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  begin
    if Message.Msg = WM_CONTEXTMENU then
    begin
      ...
    end;
    inherited;
  end;

  ...

  procedure TMyForm.CreateControl;
  var
    Ctrl: TMyControl;
  begin
    Ctrl := TMyControl.Create(Self);
    ...
  end;
  ```
- derive from the control and promote its protected `PopupMenu` property or `OnContextPopup` event to public.

  ```
  type
    TMyControl = class(TTheControl)
    public
      property PopupMenu;
    end;

  procedure TMyForm.CreateControl;
  var
    Ctrl: TMyControl;
  begin
    Ctrl := TMyControl.Create(Self);
    Ctrl.PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;
    ...
  end;
  ```

  ```
  type
    TMyControl = class(TTheControl)
    public
      property OnContextPopup;
    end;

  procedure TMyForm.CreateControl;
  var
    Ctrl: TMyControl;
  begin
    Ctrl := TMyControl.Create(Self);
    Ctrl.OnContextPopup := DoContextPopup;
    ...
  end;

  procedure TMyForm.DoContextPopup(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    PopupMenu1.Popup(...);
  end;
  ```